# Can Clinton be pardoned without being charged or convicted?

Tags: united-states, president, pardon

Is it possible for someone to be pardoned if they haven't been convicted or even charged with a crime?

Comment: Yes. Another famous example involves Canadian draft dodgers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The canonical example is Gerald Ford's [pardon of Richard Nixon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pardon_of_Richard_Nixon).

Comment: Link to legal text of pardon: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Proclamation_4311